# Jenkins job to gather all parameters needed in entire pipeline using a cron job

Tags: jenkins, cron

I want to create a Jenkins job ( stage 1)  that will gather all parameters needed throughout a build pipeline as i do not want to hard-code each stage individually as they are likely to change regularly.

In the pipeline at stage 3 there will be 5 simultaneous jobs being run with each containing different parameters which will have been got from stage 1.

Is there a way i can gather the parameters i need in stage 1 using a cron job which will be available for subsequent stages ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what is throwing everyone off answering your question is the "cron" part. What has "cron" got to do with any of this?

If we ignore that, there is an answer here that deals with a similar situation:
**[How to build a pipeline of jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528894/how-to-build-a-pipeline-of-jobs-in-jenkins)**

Using the **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**, you can collect all your parameters in the first job, and then just pass it from one job to another as environment variables, using this plugin.